# Zoom no Ipad com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma apresentação em HTML5 que roda no Ipad com controles dos slides no 'Swipe' (Deslizar pra direita ou esquerda). Porém, quando ocorre o swipe, o slide fica solto. Adicionei o seguinte código para truncar:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".wrapper").bind('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return true;
        });
    });
```

Só que com esse código, o zoom (pinch) para de funcionar. Existe alguma maneira de habilitar o zoom com esse código inserido?

Esse é ó código que não funciona.

```
node.addEventListener('gestureend', function(e) {
if (e.scale < 1.0) {
    // User moved fingers closer together
} else if (e.scale > 1.0) {
    // User moved fingers further apart
}
}, false);
```

Comment: O código que colocou na pergunta, eu não sei como aplicou, não sei como é o código da sua página, não sei como é o seu slides e também não consigo reproduzir o problema amigo. Por favor de-nos algo que possamos EXECUTAR e testar o problema primeiro por favor. O problema pode ser qualquer coisa.

Comment: Acho que eu não fui muito claro. :/

O primeiro código trunca a página, ou seja, quando desliza para o lado ele não fica 'sambando' na tela.

Mas para o zoom funcionar, é preciso tocar e fazer o movimento de pinça. O problema é que o primeiro código sobrescreve o primeiro.

Queria dar um jeito de fazer alguma ação condicional, não sei.

Tipo:

    se(movimento de pinça) {
    aplica o zoom}
    senão {
    não aplica o zoom}

Comment: O problema você já explicou né amigo, agora só falta dar um código que possamos reproduzir o problema e encontrar a origem da falha, ou que possamos elaborar um código em cima de "testes". Espero que entenda ;)